# jump to another page when I click on a button

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying that, when I click on a button it shows a alert message and go to another page

```js
function password_change_function() {
  var x = document.getElementById("password_change").value;
  alert("Password is changed");
  window.location.assign("viewprofile.php");
}
```

```html
<form>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>Current Password</strong></td>
      <td><strong>:</strong></td>
      <td><input type="password" name="currentpassword" value="ratul@aiub" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>New Password</strong></td>
      <td><strong>:</strong></td>
      <td><input type="password" name="newpassword" value="kumar@ai" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>Retype New Password</strong></td>
      <td><strong>:</strong></td>
      <td><input type="password" name="retypepassword" value="kumar@ai" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <p align="center"><input id="password_change" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="password_change_function()" /></p>
</form>
```

**the main problem is ,it shows the alert message but page not changed**

Comment: @rpm the code snippet works in Chrome as expected! what browser are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create an HTML button that acts like a link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/how-to-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link)

Comment: @NarenMurali Chrome

Answer (score 1):

you might want to try switching the last two statements around like this

```
window.location.assign("viewprofile.php");
alert("Password is changed");} // End of function scope
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>

     <script type="text/javascript">
        function password_change_function(){
           var x= document.getElementById("password_change").value;
           alert("Password is changed");
           window.location = "http://example.com/foo.php";
           }

        </script>
    <input id="password_change" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="password_change_function()"/>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your goal by swapping the two lines of code:

From this:

```
alert("Password is changed");
window.location.assign("viewprofile.php");}
```

To this:

```
window.location.assign("viewprofile.php");
alert("Password is changed");}
```

Comment: Any difference from https://stackoverflow.com/a/47857020/5468463?